# Difference between Graphical and Processor clock and underclocking a video card

Tags: windows, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

What is the difference between Graphics Clock and Processor clock? On this screenshot of NVIDIA control panel, these are two different sliders, and I don't believe that NVIDIA controls your motherboard CPU speed, so it must be GPU? But what Graphics Clock then?

What are practical guides of changing these three sliders? Say, I want to underclock my video card, because on certain games it overheats and shuts the pc down. Which sliders of the three should I change for that?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Answer from [Using nVidia System Tools Utility to Overclock Your Video Card](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/articles/65090.aspx#imgn_0), the description of the two clock frequencies match with what is said in [NVIDIA Control Panel & NVIDIA System Monitor](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiOv_OD5dzHAhUlw3IKHfhyDmw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fus.download.nvidia.com%2FWindows%2FnForce%2Fsystem_tools%2F6.06%2FNVIDIA_Control_Panel_and_System_Monitor_with_ESA_User_Guide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGu-ynHdm1eMBfcqYr2viKePNjQbQ&sig2=RRIL92ZAumWLs1kpeD9TsA&cad=rja) under System Monitor:

> Clicking the Custom option allows you to specify the core, memory, and
>   shader clock individually. Each of these components is responsible for
>   a different aspect of your video card’s performance.
>
> **Core Clock** *[ed. note: aka **Graphics clock**]*. The core clock is like the 
>   CPU of the video card. The video card’s core processor is responsible 
>   for all of the calculations needed to push graphics out to your monitor. 
>   Not surprisingly, the faster the core processor is allowed to operate, 
>   the more information it can process before it sends it to your monitor.
>
> **Memory Clock**. Don’t confuse your graphics card’s memory with your
>   computer’s memory here. The memory clock refers to the RAM on your
>   video card only. Faster video memory means faster access times and
>   less time spent storing and retrieving data.
>
> **Shader Clock** *[ed. note: aka **Processor clock**]*. Unlike ATI video cards, 
>   nVidia allows you to specify separate frequencies for the core and 
>   shader clocks. Shaders are used by 3-D games in particular to deliver 
>   graphics that are more realistic by controlling how fast calculations 
>   are made. This is one you setting you will have to play with to get 
>   the right combination of core vs. shader clock frequencies.

Now, since the tool you're using seems to use different terminology, here's the translation for core clock and shader clock (taken from [geforce.com forums](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/491694/distinguishing-between-different-clock-rates-graphics-core-processor/)):

> **The core, graphics, and GPU clock are treated as synonymous terms** for
>   the ROP domain frequency. This clock rate specifies the operating
>   speed of the raster engines (ROPs,) PolyMorph engines, and texture
>   mapping units (TMUs.) *[...]*
>
> The **processor clock refers to the shader domain frequency**, which
>   governs the speed of special function units and stream processors
>   (otherwise known as shader cores and CUDA cores) within a stream
>   multiprocessor. *[...]*

As for which setting to touch to best alleviate the heat issues, I can't give you an definitive answer. One way to approach this would be to decrease all three with some moderate amount, say 10% each, and observe how the temps change and if temps are still too high, decrease another 10%. This way you likely wouldn't produce a bottle-neck in the graphics system, thus keeping performance at a good level while still decreasing heat generation significantly.

If it is possible to tinker with the settings without needing to reboot for them to take effect (I have no first-hand experience of this) you might also just try the same with one of the clocks at a time and see how it affects the performance and temperatures.

There are also plenty of overclocking instructions, and while you're aiming for the opposite, some of those might contain relevant info on how the different parameters affect the graphics performance.

Comment: I do not have `Shader Clock` I have `Processor clock`

Comment: @zespri Please take a look at my updated answer, I clarified the terminology (my bad for not seeing the obvious difference between your screen shot and the other sources).